# How to subtract value from a column based upon a different value in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10,2,'c',6], ['tom',16 ,3,'a',8], ['tom', 22,2,'a',10],['matt', 10,1,'c',11]]

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Col a','Col c','Category', 'Value']) 
df
```

[image]

How can I set up a new column called `Calculation` where depending on the `Category` would be which column gets used in the calculation?

For example if `Category=='a'` then i could like the calculation to be `df['Value'] - df['Col a']`

My expected output should be:

```
    Name    Col a   Col c   Category    Value   Calculation
0   tom      10       2          c      6            4
1   tom      16       3          a      8           -8
2   tom      22       2          a      10          -12
3   matt     10       1          c      11           10
```

I have lots of different columns so (maybe 10 possible calculations so happy to hard code them in)

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.lookup` to get the values from the columns based on the corresponding categories then subtract them from the column `Value`:

```
df['Calc'] = df['Value'] - df.lookup(df.index, df['Category'].radd('Col '))
```

---

```
   Name  Col a  Col c Category  Value  Calc
0   tom     10      2        c      6     4
1   tom     16      3        a      8    -8
2   tom     22      2        a     10   -12
3  matt     10      1        c     11    10
```

Comment: thanks! would this work if column names are different to the `Category` value?

Comment: @SOK Can you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: If the `Category` was 'z' but its column name was called 'Z Column' then it wouldnt correspond correctly. So is there a way to hard code? would a dictionary be the best way and insert that instead of `radd('Col ')`

Comment: For lookup to work there must be the correspondence between the names..So in that case you can use `Series.map` to map the column names to category like `df['Category'].map({'a': 'Col a', 'b': 'Col b', 'c': 'Col c', 'z': 'z Column'})` instead of `.radd`